# Android AppCompact slide activities

Tags: android, animation

I have setup the following animations in android:

**Slide in right**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

**Slide out right**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

Then I have created a base class to implement the animation and all my activities extend this base class as following:

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        slideInTransition();
    }

    protected void slideInTransition() {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }
}
```

So the animations work as far as I start a new activity using startActivity(intent) and if I press back on the Toolbar (old Action Bar). But if Press back button of android the animation does not happen. 
I use the Toolbar in this way:

```
// get the actionbar as Toolbar
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.signIn_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `onBackPressed` method in your Activity

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the "back" button in the ActionBar is actually an "Up" button. Using it, takes you to a higher level of your app's navigation hierarchy. The actual "back" button would take you to the last 'place' you were at.

So have in mind that the "up" button will always take you to the same place within your app! While the "back" button might take you to a different place each time you press it, or even to another application.

Read more on this topic to understand it better here: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I marked @Fahim correct because it gives me a working solution

Comment: Sure, but if you found it useful, you can still up vote it at least :)